# Connection specific AppendShutdownHandler

Tags: c#, networkcomms.net

I'm using NetworkComms.Net and I'm currently trying to create a sort of forwarder which listens on a port (calling it GATEWAY), which receive a certain packet (from CLIENT) which will tell him where to redirect next pacekts coming from the same client.

Example:
CLIENT tell GATEWAY that he needs to get to SERVER:serverport
GATEWAY creates a connection to SERVER:serverport
CLIENT sends packets to GATEWAY which sends them to SERVER
SERVER sends back a response, which goes through the GATEWAY to the CLIENT.

I had it working with Net.Sockets and I’m now changing to NetworkComms.

The problem I’m facing is that when a connection from Gateway (client) to Server (listening server) is closed, the Gateway trigger the global callbacks for connection/disconnection:

```
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalConnectionCloseHandler(ClientDisconnected);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalConnectionEstablishHandler(ClientConnected);
```

Those callbacks are supposed to be only called when a client connect or disconnect on the Gateway

This is the code i’m currently using to start the listener.

```
NetworkComms.DefaultSendReceiveOptions = new SendReceiveOptions<ProtobufSerializer, , LZMACompressor>();
NetworkComms.DefaultSendReceiveOptions.IncludePacketConstructionTime = NetworkComms.DefaultSendReceiveOptions.ReceiveHandlePriority = QueueItemPriority.AboveNormal;
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalConnectionCloseHandler(SessionClosed);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalConnectionEstablishHandler(NewSessionConnected);
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("ECHO", SocketCommands.HandleIncomingECHOPacket);
Connection.StartListening(ConnectionType.TCP, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 10000));
```

I suppose this is like a “global” way of starting It?
How do I start one then add those Connected/Disconnected handlers to just the listener?

Thanks